# Is it possible to solve the two unknowns of this function given the area, the base length and a ratio between the start and end points?

Tags: exponential-function, indefinite-integrals, area

I am trying to calculate the values of $a$ and $b$ in the following function:
$$
f(x) = -e^{ax} + b + 1.
$$
There are a few "rules" in play:

1. $\int\limits_{0}^{n} f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x= v$
2. $f(n) = rb$

where

- $v$ is the total area of the subgraph of $f$,
- $n$ is the length of the base of this subgraph
- $r$ is the desired ratio between the start ($v_{0}$) and end ($v_{n}$) points (ex. 0.5)

Is it possible to derive equations to calculate $a$ and $b$, given $v$, $n$ and $r$? If so, would you be willing to show me how?

Comment: If $f(x) = -e^{ax} + b + 1$, then $f(0)=b$  !

Comment: $f(0)=b$ of course !

Comment: Yeah equation 2 is a given

Comment: If equation 2 is "a given", then your problem has no solution because $b=b+1$ is impossible.

Comment: $-e^{0} = -1$, not 0. Thus f(0) = b + 1

Comment: Errare humanum est. Perseverare diabolicum.

Comment: Wait, nvm. Im going to edit the second equation out

Comment: Is it possible now that I removed the incorrect assumption on my part?

Answer (score 1):

The constraints are written

$$\begin{cases}\dfrac{1-e^{an}}a+(b+1)n=v,\\-e^{an}+b+1=rb.\end{cases}$$

You can eliminate $b$ using the second equation,

$$b=\frac{1-e^{an}}{r-1},$$

which you plug in the first, giving a nasty nonlinear equation in $an$

$$\dfrac{1-e^{an}}{an}+\frac{1-e^{an}}{r-1}=\frac vn-1.$$

This must be solved by a numerical method. (There is a slight hope that it can be done with Lambert's W function, but I have not investigated.)

Comment: What is a `numerical method` if it isn't too much trouble?

Comment: @ZackR: check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm.

Comment: I am lost, how would I go about implementing this to find an answer (or at least as close to an answer as I'll get)

Comment: There is a solution in terms of the generalized Lambert function.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici how would I find this solution?

Comment: @ZackR. Have a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999 . It is very nice but almost not usable. As Yves Daoust wrote, just consider a numerical method (Newton is simple).

Comment: How do you use newtons method to derive an equation that involves 3 knowns and one unknown, such as the nonlinear equation Yves so kindly provided? @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: @ZackR. The last equation given by Yves Daoust is for a single variable $a n$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Ah good point! What about the r, n and v. From what I understand, newton's method will help me find roots. But I am not trying to solve for r, n or v. How do I incorporate this into Newton's method? Would you be willing to show me the first step and then I can repeat it on my own? If not, I understand :)

Comment: @ZackR. You wrote that $(r,n,v)$ are given. Then use Newton to solve for $an$ from which you get $a$ and $b$ is given in the answer.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici given as in will be given, I want to write a formula that takes in $(r, n, v)$ and spits out $(a, b)$. $b$ can be derived from the others, so really all I need to do is get $a$ alone on the left side of the equation. I am not seeing how I can use Newton's formula to solve this without knowing actual values for $r$, $n$ and $v$ which are variable amounts

Comment: @ZackR. You **cannot** obtain an expression. For a set of $(r,n,v)$, you need to solve the problem **numerically**

Comment: @ZackR Rather than a **formula** that takes in $r,n,v$ and spits out $a,b,$ you can construct a **procedure** that takes in $r,n,v$ and spits out $a,b$: namely, plug $r,n,v$ into the "nasty nonlinear equation" and apply Newton's formula. (I think it's a bit worse even than the answer says, because $n$ occurs by itself on the right side, so I think you have to treat $a$ rather than $an$ as the unknown.)